# Elasticsearch/Kibana search for requests longer than x characters

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I need a Query that shows me all the DNS requests that have more than 20 characters in the domain name.

I want to see anything like “mybadwebsite.hacker.com” 23 characters long – most sites are under 20.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
domain:/[a-zA-Z0-9\.]{23,}/
```

This will retrieve all documents, whose `domain` field is composed of alphanumeric characters and which is longer than 23 characters. Note that if you have a `domain.raw` field, you might be better off using it instead.

See the [regular expression syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax) that you can use in the Kibana seaerch box.